# Android: Unable to start activity java.lang.nullpointerexception

Tags: android, android-activity

I have created one `activity` And I write some functions inside `onCreate()` function.
On Running the application , I got some error message Unable to start activity `java.lang.nullpointerexception` . And I *have included* this activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.user_report_hr_full);
         List<Employee> data = new ArrayList<Employee>();
            Employee eg=new Employee();
            ListView li=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.user_report_hr_list);
            Intent myIntent = getIntent(); // this is just for example purpose
            Bundle b=myIntent.getExtras();
            Log.i("User Report by Hours", b.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(b !=null)
            {
                String username = b.getString("username");
                String userid = b.getString("userid");
                String startdate = b.getString("startdate");
                String enddate = b.getString("enddate");
                String mode=b.getString("mode");
                Log.i("LOOP", userid+"-"+startdate+"-"+enddate+"-"+mode);
                data=eg.getReports(username, userid, startdate, enddate,mode);
                Log.i("Get Report",data.toString());
                li.setAdapter(new UserHoursByReportArrayadapter(getApplicationContext(),data));
            }


    }
```

And My Log file is

```
05-08 11:45:30.745: I/User Report by HoursActivity:mode(517): 1
05-08 11:45:30.837: I/User Report by Hours(517): Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=236]
05-08 11:45:30.845: I/LOOP(517): 1-2012-04-08-2012-05-08-1
05-08 11:45:30.855: D/HTTP(517): Execute HTTP Post Request
05-08 11:45:30.855: D/UserID(517): Userid in EmpGlobal [1]
05-08 11:45:30.855: D/Start date(517): Start date in EmpGlobal [2012-04-08]
05-08 11:45:30.855: D/End date(517): End date in EmpGlobal [2012-05-08]
05-08 11:45:30.855: D/Mode(517): Mode in EmpGlobal [1]
05-08 11:45:48.275: I/log_tag(517):  Time: 2033755
05-08 11:45:48.275: I/log_tag(517):  project name: AndroidTimesheet
05-08 11:45:48.285: I/log_tag(517):  username: admin1
05-08 11:45:48.285: I/log_tag(517):  Time: 34692
05-08 11:45:48.285: I/log_tag(517):  project name: Google
05-08 11:45:48.285: I/log_tag(517):  username: admin1
05-08 11:45:48.285: I/Get Report(517): [com.technogems.employeetimecard.EmployeeGlobal@44da2ca8, com.technogems.employeetimecard.EmployeeGlobal@44da2f88]
05-08 11:45:48.285: I/User Report by HoursAdapter(517): Inside constructor
05-08 11:45:48.285: D/AndroidRuntime(517): Shutting down VM
05-08 11:45:48.285: W/dalvikvm(517): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
05-08 11:45:48.285: E/AndroidRuntime(517): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
05-08 11:45:48.295: E/AndroidRuntime(517): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.technogems.employeetimecard/com.technogems.employeetimecard.UserHoursByReport}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-08 11:45:48.295: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
05-08 11:45:48.295: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
05-08 11:45:48.295: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
05-08 11:45:48.295: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
05-08 11:45:48.295: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-08 11:45:48.295: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-08 11:45:48.295: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
05-08 11:45:48.295: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 11:45:48.295: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-08 11:45:48.295: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
05-08 11:45:48.295: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
05-08 11:45:48.295: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-08 11:45:48.295: E/AndroidRuntime(517): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-08 11:45:48.295: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at com.technogems.employeetimecard.UserHoursByReport.onCreate(UserHoursByReport.java:35)
05-08 11:45:48.295: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-08 11:45:48.295: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
05-08 11:45:48.295: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  ... 11 more
```

Please provide me the proper way to start that activity

Comment: It looks like your UserHoursByReport class is causing the issue, could you post that code?

Comment: This works:  Log.i("Get Report",data.toString()); so I assume your problem is/starts in this line: li.setAdapter(new UserHoursByReportArrayadapter(getApplicationContext(),data));

Comment: @Tobold ok how can i overcome this

Comment: I don't think the error is in this line, nor in this method or class. Check out your UserHoursByReportArrayadapter class and see where you are creating an UserHoursByReport instance. The exception is thrown at line 35 in UserHoursByReport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line :
**Log.i("User Report by Hours", b.toString());**
Where b is null So the nullpointerException occured

Comment: I believe this line is alright, see the log: 05-08 11:45:30.837: I/User Report by Hours(517): Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=236]

Comment: @Tobold I have changed the layout for that activity , now its working. I didnt know how that problem is solved